# sqlite distinct rows, based on multiple colms

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to run a sqlite query which return a non repeating of certain col. (i am no sql expert, and google cant seem to help me).

The goal is to select unique combinations of `branch`, `section`, `year`, and `p1_p2`, and for each unique combination, only select `admission_number` and `passowrd`, just once

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    admission_number TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    branch TEXT NOT NULL,
    section INTEGER NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    p1_p2 TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Extra: I am using aiosqlite 0.19.0, python 3.12

---

i tried, something

```sql
SELECT admission_number, password, DISTINCT(branch, year, section, p1_p2)
FROM users;
```

and obv , it raise Error,

---

i want something which works like this logic

```py
seen: list[tuple] = []
for id, admission_number, password, branch, section, year, p1_p2 in users:
    if (branch, section, year, p1_p2) not in seen:
        seen.append(branch, section, year, p1_p2)
        yield admission_number, password
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an agregator on the columns you want to select just ounce, you can use group by instead of distinct to look for combinations of the columns you want.

here is an example :

```
SELECT branch, section, year, p1_p2, MIN(admission_number) AS admission_number, MIN(password) AS password
FROM users
GROUP BY branch, section, year, p1_p2;
```